# Is there a way to load data from snowflake to google sheets directly?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am seeking to connect snowflake directly into google sheets, without using python or anything else.

I have saved queries and want the output put directly into google sheets.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to automate this programmatically, or interactively while exploring data? Please share mare context.

Comment: This question was asked before. The answers are still the same:
[Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047903/google-sheets-connecting-to-snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake community forum answers this here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D7Do000000cpXjKAI/detail

TLDR is that you can use some sort of ETL tool. Airbyte (ETL), Census (Reverse ETL), Bracket (2-way syncs) all work, it just depends on your use case. All of them lean towards being developer friendly and have docs to get started so I won't explain that here. But if it's not clear, here's an explanation on those tools

ETL tools: move all data into a central place like Snowflake
Reverse ETL tools: move data back into Google Sheets from Snowflake
2-way syncs: use Google sheets as a UI for Snowflake. You can read, write, or both from a spreadsheet

1. (https://airbyte.com) is ETL
2. (https://getcensus.com) is Reverse ETL
3. (https://usebracket.com) is 2 way syncs